# OnePlus Watch 2 force stop my application when screen turns of and it cancels all scheduled alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wear-os, android-alarms

I have a Wear OS application which is working fine since the original Android Wear; even on Wear OS 4 Samsung watches. Problem is on the new OnePlus Watch 2, which is a Wear OS 4 device, but with some bigger changes to improve battery (which is awesome :))

Once I close the app's `Activity` and the watch turns its screen of, it force stops my application with logs in the LogCat:

```
ActivityManager system_server Force stopping <my package name> ....
ActivityManager system_server Killing 31668: <my package name> ....
CarrierSvcBindHelper com.android.phone onHandleForceStop: [<my package name>]
ActivityManager system_server Got obituary of 31668:<my package name>
```

And after that all my scheduled alarms, scheduled via `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` and `setAlarmClock()` are removed from the pending alarms -- checked via `adb shell dumpsys alarm` which doesn't show my alarms anymore.

If I just minimize the Activity, then the alarms stay scheduled and evertyhing works as expected (confirmed with `adb shell dumpsys alarm`). Is this some new behaviour in Wear OS 4/Android 13 or a bug in OnePlus Watch 2? How can I reliably schedule alarms on this watch?